# Rewrite urls to not include file extensions but allow subdomains to act normally

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

I need to

- Remove the file extension from all of the urls on my site (mywebsite.com/about.html >> mywebsite.com/about/)
- Always add a trailing / to the end of the url (mywebsite.com/about >> mywebsite.com/about/)
- Allow for an exception that one of the nav items links to a pdf, not an html document (mywebsite.com/calendar.pdf >> mywebsite.com/calendar/
- Allow subdomains to go to their folder instead of being rewritten (My folder tree is public_html>my main site files and a dev folder>(inside dev folder) index.html) I need the subdomain to link to that dev folder, currently the url rewriting changes dev.mywebsite.com to public_html/dev.html

This is my current, hacked together htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^calendar/?$ files/2013-2014_calendar.pdf
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Sorry, this might be a duplicate or semi-duplicate. I looked around as much as I could but couldn't find anything that applied to my situation exactly or that I understood. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# skip dev. subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# calendar rule
RewriteRule ^calendar/?$ files/2013-2014_calendar.pdf [L]

# hide .html rules
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L,NE]

# add a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks so much. I have to get more familiar with RegExp and this rewrite stuff. Do you perhaps know how to force it to add the trailing "/"? That's the only issue with your code.

Comment: I have `RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L,NE]` which force `/` in the end.

Comment: Hmmm... That part doesn't seem to be working (except for mywebsite.com/dev). Either one with or without the trailing slash it loads right. I would like it to change the url in the client from without slash to with slash. Could you explain what the lines in the hide .html rules section do?

Comment: If you note `# hide .html rules` there in `RewriteRule` I have `%1/` which forces a trailing slash after every redirect of `/abc.html` to `/abc/`

Comment: Ahh, I see. What if I want to make sure that if I put in a URL like mysite.com/abc it will go to mysite.com/abc/  Would that be done like, # hide .html rules
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L,NE]   ??